# Is there any reliable way to check if a download is complete in django

Tags: django, nginx, django-views, download

I am using nginx to serve files via a django view and I need to be able to detect when the file download is complete. Is there any way to reliable read the download status.

Comment: do you want to prevent direct file linking?

Comment: No, the file is a zip being served via a view and I want to find a way to determine when the file has finished downloading so I can remove the zip file.